# Visual studio causes circular references when 2 web services consume each other

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

I have 2 webservices that needs to talk to each other, and also be available to a client.
Because of this i thought it would be a good idea to create a Consumer project that can be referenced by the client and and the serviceImplementation, so i only have to update it once.

Doing this doesnt cause any problems from the client, but when the services try to use each others Consumer project. Visual studio complains about a circular reference.

I have devided my project like so

- Test1.ServiceConsumer
- Test1.ServiceHost
- Test1.ServiceImplementation
- Test2.ServiceConsumer
- Test2.ServiceHost
- Test2.ServiceImplementation

Test1.ServiceImplementation holds a code reference to Test2.ServiceConsumer and when i try to add Test2.ServiceImplementation code reference to Test1.ServiceConsumer i get the circular reference error.

The service Consumer doesnt have anything to do with the actual service host or service implementation when looking at code references, so i cant figure out why this happens. If i edit the project file manually, Visual studio still show an error but everything builds and run.

One solution would be to create a service reference for each ServiceImplementation, but then i would have to update it twice when adding new stuff.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is create one project that contains the Service Reference. Set the proxy generation to Public so that all the generated classes are available from outside of the project. Now reference the service project from your implementation and consumer projects.

```
                                     ServiceContract
                                        ^      ^
                                        |      |
               Test1.ServiceImplementation    Test2.ServiceImplementation
                            ^                              ^
                            |                              |
                   Test1.ServiceHost              Test2.ServiceHost
```

This way there is no circular reference. Any shared contract classes need to live inside the ServiceContract assembly.

You could also use the `ChannelFactory` pattern which will allow you to completely do away with the need to "generate" a service client. Stick the interfaces and the datacontracts in their own shared assembly and then use the ChannelFactory to create a client proxy on the fly.

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. I though this was what i did by having the Service Reference in the Consumer project.

Comment: You currently have 2 consumer projects.